# java - calling synchronized method from inside synchronized while waiting

Tags: java

is it possible to call a synchronized method from inside a synchronized method while waiting for resource to become available (using wait())? thanks

Comment: This question should be rephrased. While Michael's answer is technically correct, the question is unclear if you are asking about a single simple re-entrant synchronization block or something more complex. Synchronization blocks and concurrency need to be looked at in their entire context.

Comment: Also: if a thread is waiting for something to happen (in an `Object.wait(...)` call), it is not in a position to call anything.  Some illustrative code is required, IMO.

Answer (score 9):

Java's mutexes are recursive, so you can invoke a synchronized method recursively or invoke another synchronized method for which you already hold a lock. You will need to tell us what it is you are specifically trying to do, though.... lots of stuff with thread locking/synchronization, if done incorrectly, can lead to deadlock, and it isn't entirely clear from your question what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

No. there's no way to check whether a given object's monitor is currently on hold in java, or an atomic way to "check and grab" the object's lock.

You may want to check out the standard java package http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html though. the class Lock has the functionality tryLock(), which can try to gain the lock (so if your thread fails to get hold of the lock, then it can do something else depending on the return value of tryLock()).